# How  can i create another view? Cocos2d

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone

i want to create a new view in Cocos2d programmatically

can you help me on how can i do this? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add uiviews to cocos2d with this line 
`[[[[CCDirector sharedDirector] glView] window] addSubview: yourUIView];`

Comment: i tried it but when i compile it says (director may not respond to glView) then i receive SIGABRT i tried to delete the glView and same goes to window. 

i tried this : `UIView *myView = [[UIView alloc]init];
[[[[Director sharedDirector]glView]window]addSubview:myView];
[myView release];`

Comment: Thanks for you effort i have found a solution now :)

Comment: I didn't have my computer with me at the time. You could try openGLView instead of glView. It depends on which version of cocos2d and how you set it up. Usually you can see what it is called in the code setting up the open GL view in the app delegate.